# Does PHP dockblock has some kind of @mixin for interfaces?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, docblocks

My Visual Studio Code shows "undefined method". I want to know is it possible to "fix" it with some VSC settings or maybe there is a PHP solution.  I have this

```php
class A
{
    public function someMethodA()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class B extends A implements Bint
{
    public function someMethodB()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

interface BInt
{
    public function someMethodB();
}

class C
{
    public function someMethodC(Bint $b)
    {
        // VSC shows indefined method
        return $b->someMethodA();
    }
}
```

My interface doesn't have `someMethodA`, is it possible to "inherit" it from `Class A` to get rid of "error"? This class comes from a package, it has no interface and I need to extend it

`getStatusCode()` exists, it is public, everything works, but Visual Studio Code cannot understand it

[image]

Comment: You have two different examples here. In your first example, the IDE is correct, the variable `$b` *might not* have `someMethodA`; in the second example (the image), you haven't actually shown the interface, but there is more complicated code in the method which may be relevant to the question. Please [edit] to make sure you include the code you're actually interested in, as code and not images.

Comment: @IMSoP Hi there, my question is exactly about **might not have** but it definitely has (because of parent class A). Interface however doesn't have this method (that is why IDE showing this error). Should I import all methods from parent A (I have no control over it) into interface or there some elegant solution for this? The code is correct, I can edit, but it is will be irrelevant data in my opinion. Image is just for showing type of error to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focussing on your code example, not your screenshot, your IDE is correct, and you should listen to what it's telling you.

The contract of method `someMethodC` is that it can accept **any** implementation of interface `Bint`. That *guarantees* that you can call `someMethodB`, but **does not guarantee anything else**.

**If** the method is passed an instance of class A, then PHP will allow you to call `someMethodA` on it, but **it might be passed some other object**, such as:

```
class OnlyB implements Bint {
    public function someMethodB() {
        // ..
    }
}
```

The contract (signature) of someMethodC says you can pass this object, but when you call `someMethodA`, you will get an error.

If you want the method to *always* receive instances of class A, say so in the signature:

```
public function someMethodC(A $b) {
    return $b->someMethodA();
}
```

If you want it to accept *any* implementation of `Bint`, then you should only call methods guaranteed to exist by that interface.